# angularJS $window not defined

Tags: angularjs, syntax, window, angularjs-config

**UPDATE: I understand that $window cannot be pick up (i.e. other post) but what is my alternative to get that global variable into my .config??**

I am having issues with `$window`, I have a global variable set on my main page and I am trying to get angularJS to pick up on it but this is the error I get:

**> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module docMan due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $window**

As you can see below I try to inject it into the `.config`, I did the same in the controller but it still doesn't let me us it, not sure why...
Any help would be appreciated!

```
 app.config(['$httpProvider','$window',function ($httpProvider, $window) {
     var sessionId = $window.__sfdcSessionId;
     $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
     delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["content-type"] = "application/json";
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "OAuth " + sessionId ;
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-User-Agent'] = "MyClient" ;
    }]) ;
```

Comment: So what is my alternative here to pick up on a global variable???

Comment: I swith .config to .run and now I get this error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $httpProviderProvider <- $httpProvider